# Give alias / column definition list to ROWS FROM()

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-10, set-returning-functions, alias

This obviously doesn't work:

```
SELECT regexp_matches[1], regexp_matches[1]
FROM ROWS FROM (
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:upper:]]', 'g'),
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:lower:]]', 'g')
);
```

> Error: [42702] column reference "regexp_matches" is ambiguous

How can I give an alias to the function calls?

```
SELECT u[1], l[1]
FROM ROWS FROM (
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:upper:]]', 'g'),
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:lower:]]', 'g')
) AS (u text[], l text[]);
```

> Error: [42601] ROWS FROM() with multiple functions cannot have a column definition list
>
> *Hint: Put a separate column definition list for each function inside ROWS FROM().*

```
SELECT u[1], l[1]
FROM ROWS FROM (
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:upper:]]', 'g') AS (u text[]),
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:lower:]]', 'g') AS (l text[])
);
```

> Error: [42601] a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"

I'm out of ideas. This has to be possible.

Documentation:

- [Syntax of `ROWS FROM()` (7.2.1.4. Table Functions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)
- [`regexp_matches` returns `setof text[]` (Table 9.9. Other String Functions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table alias too

```
SELECT T.u[1], t.l[1]
FROM ROWS FROM (
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:upper:]]', 'g'),
  regexp_matches('fooBarBaz', '[[:lower:]]', 'g')
) AS t (u, l);
```

Comment: I've tried it with a table alias, too. The key was to omit the column types.

Comment: Can you omit the table alias?

Comment: Only when I also omit the column list. But then I'm back to square one. The syntax from your snippet is probably the only one that works.